# Want to change the context path in Spring boot application in an external Tomact server version 9

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I want to deploy a Spring boot application in an external Tomcat server version 9. I am able to deploy it and working the endpoints also. But properties I have set in `application.properties` file those are not working. Like `server.servlet.context-path=/myapp` is is not working instead the context path which I am getting is `http://localhost:8080/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/ping`.

I am using 2.3.10.RELEASE and Java 1.8 and Tomcat version 9.0.46 Can anyone please help me out with this.

But everything is perfectly working on embedded tomcat. Thanks in advance and any suggestion, comment is highly appreciated.

Can anyone please help me with how I can do this - My war file name would be myapp-0.1.war but the context path of the application would be like this localhost:8080/myapp/api/ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use finalName property in your build file (pom.xml for maven)

```
<finalName>myapp</finalName>
```

Comment: Thanks, Alien it works. But if the war name is like myapp-0.1.war then it will not work. I am searching for something where my war file name would be myapp-0.1.war but the corresponding context path will be /myapp. So that the existing endpoint will work as expected. http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/ping

Comment: It will make sure that after maven build the war file name will be the same which you pass in final name.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with how I can do this - My war file name would be myapp-0.1.war but the context path of the application would be like this localhost:8080/myapp/api/ping

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Spring Boot application in an external servlet container, the `server.*` properties **do not** apply.

If you are willing to change the naming convention you can drop a WAR file named `myapp##0.1.war` in the `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` directory and benefit from parallel deployment (cf. [parallel deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment)).

If you want to stick to your naming convention, you can create a folder for your WAR files (e.g. `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps-available`) and create a deployment descriptor `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/<engine_name>/<host_name>/<context_path>.xml` (in your case probably `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml`) with the following content:

```xml
<Context docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps-available/myapp-0.1.war" />
```